# linear Diophantine equation with real coefficients

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am studying linear Diophantine equations with real coefficients:
\begin{equation}
ax+by=1\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
I have no clue about where to begin; could someone please point me to some starting point? I was not able to find anything in the question database.

Comment: $x, y$ should be integers while $a,b$ are real?

Comment: Exactly, for instance $\pi\cdot 2+(1/2-\pi)\cdot 2=1$